# Drawing error on toolbar and statusbar after upgrade to AppCompat v21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have upgraded my app to AppCompat v21 for the Material Design look and feel. I am using the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` widged instead of the ActionBar. After the upgrade I experience a weird drawing error in the statusbar, the toolbar and the navigation area (see screenshots). The rest of the layout is fine.

The error occurs only sometimes after some activity launches and is not really reproducable. The error occurs on my Nexus 5 running on stock Android 5.0.1.

Does anyone know a possible cause for this behavior?

Statusbar & Toolbar (the blue color is the desired `@color/colorPrimary`):
[image: Drawing error screenshot 1]

Content looks fine.

Navigation:
[image: Drawing error screenshot 2]

My layout is very simple, so I do not think this is the cause of the behavior, however here the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here my toolbar style:

```
<style name="Theme.AppThemeBase.Toolbar.Dark" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:navigationIcon">?attr/homeAsUpIndicator</item>
    <item name="navigationIcon">?attr/homeAsUpIndicator</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Try add 'android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"' to Toolbar widget layout

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work, still these strange pixels...

Comment: Ok I put my style file to the answer, I use it work fine.

Comment: Hi jeff_bordon, how is going on, is working?

Comment: I have tried it and I have not seen the strange pixels for a while. I think `windowActionBar` did the trick. Weird thoug because my theme was already inheriting from parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`... Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Sorry to say, but the error still occurs sometimes... very strange, maybe it is a Nexus 5 issue? Have not seen this issue on the emulator...

Comment: I am using Galaxy Nexus, is working fine. Anyway hope you will figure out your problem.

Comment: On some devices you will experience that effect when every layer of app UI is transparent so GPU have nothing to render, on some devices that space is black. So I think that something is wrong with your styles and in some conditions toolbar is not getting proper bg, maybe it's platform specific?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Style file:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>   
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/bg_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_grey</item>
</style>
```

Above you have to use:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

to disable default action bar !!!

also Toolbar widget layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>
```

and color file:

```
<resources>
   <color name="bg_blue">#1277c4</color>
   <color name="dark_grey">#666666</color>
</resources>
```

Hope this help.